# What is a RemoteService error in Android?

Tags: android

I get a RemoteServiceException error on Android Pie
But I can't figure out where this error occurs

```
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1894)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7156)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Can you tell me where the error occurs with the above log only?
Thanks for reading

Comment: Can you add code, error case detail

Comment: I can't see any more data on Google Play Console
Is there a way to check?